# How do I add a scoped DbContext to my ASP NET Core API Controllers that uses EntityFrameworkCore and SSH tunneling into MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, ssh, entity-framework-core

I have the following ConfigureServices() content in my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<GMContext>(options =>
            {

                var myConnectionSettings = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionSettings").Get<ConnectionSettings>();
                var sshSettings = myConnectionSettings.SSH;
                var databaseSettings = myConnectionSettings.Database;
                string keyFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test4");
                var authMethods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>
                {
                    new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(sshSettings.UserName, new PrivateKeyFile(keyFilePath))
                };
                using (var sshClient = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(sshSettings.Server,
                    sshSettings.Port, sshSettings.UserName, authMethods.ToArray())))
                {
                    sshClient.Connect();
                    var forwardedPort = new ForwardedPortLocal(databaseSettings.BoundHost, databaseSettings.Host,
                        databaseSettings.Port);
                    sshClient.AddForwardedPort(forwardedPort);
                    forwardedPort.Start();


                    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder csb;
                    csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
                    {
                        Server = databaseSettings.BoundHost,
                        Port = forwardedPort.BoundPort,
                        UserID = databaseSettings.UserName,
                        Password = databaseSettings.Password,
                        Database = databaseSettings.DatabaseName
                    };
                    options.UseMySQL(csb.ConnectionString);
                }

            });
```

I then pick up the context in a controller and attempt to query the context I get a connection denied error:

```
namespace CoreGMWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CropController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CropController> _logger;
        private readonly GMContext _context;
        public CropController(ILogger<CropController> logger, GMContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a Sample Items
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<TCountries>> GetSampleItems()
        {
                var result = _context.TCountries.Take(10).ToList();
                return result;
        }
        
    }
}
```

The Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is
> likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error
> resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.
> ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.  --->
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No connection
> could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
> 127.0.31.1:54960)  ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException
> (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine
> actively refused it. 127.0.31.1:54960    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(Exception
> source)    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.<>c.b__28_1(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
> requiresSynchronization)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
> includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)    at
> MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
> settings)    at
> MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
> settings)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
> settings)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean
> errorsExpected)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean
> errorsExpected)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject
> parameterObject)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)    at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
> CoreGMWebAPI.Controllers.CropController.GetSampleItem() in
> C:\Users\lobos\source\repos\CoreGMWebAPI\CoreGMWebAPI\Controllers\CropController.cs:line
> 31    at lambda_method(Closure , Object )    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> HEADERS
> ======= Accept: application/json Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ca;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,nb;q=0.6 Connection:
> close Host: localhost:44313 Referer:
> https://localhost:44313/swagger/index.html User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36 dnt: 1 sec-fetch-site: same-origin
> sec-fetch-mode: cors sec-fetch-dest: empty sec-gpc: 1

When I run the following quick test inside the ConfigureServices() method in Startup.cs it connects and queries without any issues:

```
                          ...
                        options.UseMySQL(csb.ConnectionString);

                        var otherOps = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GMContext>();
                        otherOps.UseMySQL(csb.ConnectionString);
                        using (var context = new GMContext(otherOps.Options))
                        {
                            var testRun = context.TCountries.Take(3).ToList();
                        }
```

This leads me to suspect that the SSHClient is closing before the Controller can use the dbContext. Should I somehow be passing the SSHClient  as well as the dbContext? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The same way you add every other DbContext - with `AddDbContext. SshClient is unrelated. You could open an SSH session when the application starts and close it when it ends. Unlike pooled connections, opening an SSH session is expensive so it makes little sense to keep opening a new one for every database call

Comment: In your code though, you're never using the SSH channel. You open it, retrieve the forwarded port then close it. The SSH channel is closed when your controller tries to use the DbContext instance

Comment: Where should I introduce the SSH client? Somewhere else in Startup?